# Php shadow login into forums and return data to iframe

Tags: php, html

I have a page whit login forums

```
<a href="https://www.Forum1.com/en/login" target="myiframe">Forum1</a> &nbsp;
<a href="http://Forum2.be/Login.aspx" target="myiframe">Forum2</a> &nbsp;
<a href="https://Forum3.forum.com/desktop/" target="myiframe">Forum3</a>
</br>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="myiframe"></iframe>
<p><a href="?action=logOut">LogOut</a></p>
```

I have  registration credentials in each of them, I have 5 people who want read this forums with my credentials, I do not want to show them credentials but I want to let whem read thoose forums with my credentials. So in my page on href pressed in iframe must be loaded content of each forum already with my credentials (which must be not shown to user) (so i dont warry what they can change any info or something else in my profiles). Also i need to track what whey do on forums to control who what can do ( such thing which link is pressed).

It is possible to do with PHP? Please show me i right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's way easier to let those users register a own account.

In case you still want to use a PHP code to let those users view the forum without knowing your credentials, you could create a PHP class like this:

```
<?php
    class Forum
    {
        var $url = '';

        public function getContent()
        {
            $content = @file_get_contents($this->url);
            return $content;
        }
    }
?>
```

and create objects for each forum u want to show.

```
<?php
    require_once('Forum.php');
    $getForum = new Forum();
    $getForum->url = 'http://www.google.de';
    echo $getForum->getContent();
?>
```

That's just a example though, you would have to add your credentials and might use http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php to sign in to the forum.